# Recreating line pattern in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How do I recreate this pattern in illustrator?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use this shape to create a Pattern from **Menu Object** > **Pattern** > **Make**

[image: pattern]

- Define the Pattern parameters: the top and bottom vertex should contact

[image: vertices]

- Fill a rectangle using the pattern
- Move the pattern inside the rectangle: at the bottom there must be a vertex, the width is the pattern module width.

[image: rectangle]

- For moving or scaling a pattern inside a shape, check only **Transform Pattern** at the Transform Window.

[image: move]

- Duplicate the rectangle and flip it vertically

[image: flip]

**Result**

[image]